# Validate user's input

Tags: c#, logic

I have 3 text boxes: textbox1, textbox2, textbox3. Users only allow to fill out information in one text box.

```
private string determineSearchParameter()
{
    //Execute statements if ALL textboxes are empty
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox1.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox2.Text) &&
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox3.Text))
    {
        return "Please Enter a Search Parameter";
    }
    //Execute all fields have an input
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox2.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox1.Text) &&
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox3.Text))
    {
        return "Please only enter one Criteria";
    }
    //Execute statments if multiple textboxes have values
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox3.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox1.Text))
    {
        return "Please only enter one Criteria";
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox3.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox2.Text))
    {
        return "Please only enter one Criteria";
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox2.Text))
    {
        return "Please only enter one Criteria";
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox1.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox2.Text) &&
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox3.Text))
    {
        return "Something else";
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox2.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text) &&
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox3.Text))
    {
        return "Something there";
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox3.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text) &&
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox2.Text))
    {
        return "Something here";
    }
    return "";
}
```

Is there another way to validate these text boxes? I would prefer a shorter version of this.

Comment: please revise this question to make the question clear and remove some of the extraneous code. simplify it down the smallest amount needed to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
var state1 = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox1.Text);
var state2 = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox2.Text);
var state3 = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox3.Text);

if (!(state1 || state2 || state3))
{
    return "Please Enter a Search Parameter";
}
if (!(state1 ^ state2 ^ state3))
{
    return "Please only enter one Criteria";
}
if (state1)
{
    return "Something else";
}
if (state2)
{
    return "Something there";
}
return "Something here";
```

Comment: I think you missed the case where all states are true. Thank you for your XOR suggestion.